# I have used colorbox to one equation, how to use colorbox to two in align?

Tags: math-mode, align, highlighting

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\frame {
\begin{equation*}\text{\colorbox{white!90!black}{
$
\textcolor{red!70!black}{\min \quad f(x),}
$}}
\end{equation*} 

\textcolor{red!70!black}{
\begin{align*}
\min \quad&f(x) \\
s.t.\quad &c_i(x)=0,           
\end{align*}}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that you don't need to load the `xcolor` package with beamer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to load `xcolor`. It's already included in the `beamer` class. In case you actually want to append some additional options let's say to `xcolor`, use the options of the `beamer`, e.g.

```
\documentclass[...,svgnames]{beamer}
```

which is going to load extra colour setting for the `xcolor`; see the section 4.3 of the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to see the extra colours.

EDIT. As suggested in comments, there is a more recommended way to pass options to `xcolor` package

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}
```

Another point is when we specify colours, the `white` is always appended as the last one. So the expression `white!90!black` is equivalent to `black!10` because this in turn is equivalent to `black!10!white`.

As to your problem, you could just wrap a centred inline equation with an inner variant of a regular math environment, e.g. `align` -> `aligned` (see [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) for more info).

Here's one example. BTW, `\fboxsep` controls margins in boxes.

```latex
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}
\colorlet{mbg}{black!10}
\colorlet{mfg}{red!70!black}
\setlength\fboxsep{5pt}


\begin{document}
\frame{
  \begin{center}
    \colorbox{mbg}{\color{mfg}$\min \quad f(x)$} 
  \end{center}
  
  \begin{center}
    \colorbox{mbg}{\color{mfg}\(
      \begin{aligned}
        \min \quad & f(x) \\
        s.t. \quad & c_i(x)=0
      \end{aligned}
      \)}
  \end{center}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks really for your help! Your help is not only for my questions, but also for the other problems in my tex.

Comment: @Celdor I would suggest a tiny change. Instead of using `svgnames` as class option and thus passing it to all packages, I would suggest `\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}` so that it only gets passed on to the package where it is needed.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks. It's a good point. I've included your suggestion.

Comment: @Celdor :thumbsup:

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the `empheq` package:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand*\mygraybox[1]{%
    \colorbox{white!90!black}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

{\color{red!70!black}
\begin{empheq}[box=\mygraybox]{equation*}
\min \quad f(x),
\end{empheq}}

{\color{red!70!black}
\begin{empheq}[box=\mygraybox]{align*}
\min \quad&f(x) \\
s.t.\quad &c_i(x)=0,           
\end{empheq}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could combine it with the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,frame hidden,colback=white!90!black,sharp corners}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{equation*}
\color{red!70!black} \min \quad f(x),
\end{empheq} 

{\color{red!70!black}
\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align*}
\min \quad&f(x) \\
s.t.\quad &c_i(x)=0,           
\end{empheq}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You gave me different options and pointed out problems in my file. Thanks indeed from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: @SanaGreen You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

[image]

The code :

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
\text{\colorbox{white!90!black}{$\textcolor{red!70!black}{\min \quad f(x),}$}} \quad
\min \quad& f(x) \\
\textcolor{red!70!black}{s.t.} \quad & c_i(x) = 0,
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```